# How to convert a textfile into a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, text, text-files

I want to convert this textfile:

```
(516, 440)
(971, 443)
(1186, 439)
(1402, 441)
(1630, 449)
(299, 681)
(518, 684)
(736, 691)
(739, 431)
```

into a list that look's like this:

```
List = [
(516, 440),
(971, 443),
(1186, 439),
(1402, 441),
(1630, 449),
(299, 681),
(518, 684),
(736, 691),
(739, 431)
]
```

The answer that I found here is not working for me, because of the commas in the brackets (). Does sombody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on each line:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = [
        literal_eval(line.rstrip()) for line in f
    ]
    print(data)
```

Result:

```
[(516, 440), (971, 443), (1186, 439), (1402, 441), (1630, 449), (299, 681), (518, 684), (736, 691), (739, 431)]
```